# ActiveRecord::Relation.concat failing in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activerecord-relation

Stupid question but I'm not sure why this would work in Rails 4.2 but not in Rails 5.2.

```
FamilyCharacteristic.where(family_id: @user.family_ids)
                    .concat(@user.characteristics)
```

Specs fail in 5.2:

```
Failure/Error:
       FamilyCharacteristic.where(family_id: @user.family_ids)
                           .concat(@user.characteristics)

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `concat' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
       Did you mean?  count
```

Was concat removed from `ActiveRecord::Relation` in 5.2 or was `FamilyCharacteristic.where(family_id: @user.family_ids)` somehow a different object in < 4.2?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you want to do? Can you show me your models?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did some digging and found out that:

- `FamilyCharacteristic.where(family_id: @user.family_ids)`'s class didn't change, it's still `ActiveRecord::Relation`
- `Relation` didn't and still doesn't define its own `concat` method, but it was delegated to `Array#concat` until [this commit happened](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9d79334a1dee67e31222c790e231772deafcaeb8#diff-563ce9140aa399b5ba97bb2a64b7c568), so in Rails 4.2 `SomeModel.where(id: ids).concat(some_records)`(which returns an `Array`) was actually the same as `SomeModel.where(id: ids).to_a.concat(some_models)`
- After [mentioned before change](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9d79334a1dee67e31222c790e231772deafcaeb8#diff-563ce9140aa399b5ba97bb2a64b7c568) in `ActiveRecord::Delegation`, in Rails 5.2, the only methods delegated to `Array` are the ones specified in this module and `concat` is not among them

To sum up - `concat` from your example was never part of `ActiveRecord` but was delegated to `Array#concat` and that's why it worked. It's no longer delegated in Rails 5 so it throws `NoMethodError`.

Comment: Excellent sleuthing, thanks!  Suggestions for simple workaround? Seems like whatever this app was doing before might not have been considered a best practice.

Comment: Instead of `concat` you can just use `+` to make it work most similarly - `FamilyCharacteristic.where(family_id: @user.family_ids) + @user.characteristics`. There are also methods like `merge` - but it uses sql `AND` clause, `or` - uses `OR` clause so it seems like the right solution but it requires relations to be structurally compatible so I don't think it would work in this case.

Comment: Interestingly, using `concat` on association works [completely differently](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionAssociation/concat). For example: `SomeModel.where(user: user).concat(some_records)` just produces array with records in it whereas `user.some_models.concat(some_records)` works like `<<` so it actually UPDATES `some_records` to belong to the user.

Comment: I couldn't get `+` to work. Finally settled on this kludge: `FamilyCharacteristic.where(family_id: @user.family_ids).to_a.concat(@user.characteristics.to_a)` that "works" but would love a more elegant solution.

Comment: I don't know your models and associations but if `@user.characteristics` are of `FamilyCharacteristic` type you can also try something like `FamilyCharacteristic.where(family_id: @user.family_ids).or(FamilyCharacteristic.where(user: @user))`, which will produce just one SQL query and take care of possible duplicates. I assumed a few things about your models so this might not be an exact solution.